# c# child form close by itself after one of it functions finished

Tags: c#, winforms

child form (called by parent form `code 1`) with name `call_order` close by itself after button click function finished. in button click function i work with DataBase and set a local variable that `Get_Result` return to parent form. i think its not about my code, problem must be somewhere else but i can't found it, if you have an idea appreciate. also in `keydown` function of `call_order` i have checked that if the key is `escape` then `this.close();` that suppose to close form when user press `escape`.

```
code1: in parent form
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F12) {
  call_order call_order = new call_order(today_sale);
  call_order.ShowDialog();
  today_sale = Convert.ToInt64(call_order.Get_Result);
}
```

in button click function of call_order form i have this:

```
if (shomare_eshterake_user != "")
        {
            int success = save_one_sale();
            if (success == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("something");
                shomare_moshtari_fish.Text = Convert.ToString(shomare_fish_phone_user);
                docPrint.Print();
                shomare_moshtari_fish.Text = Convert.ToString(shomare_fish_phone_user + 1);
            }
            else if (success == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("something");
            }
            else if (success == 3)
            {
                nan_barbari_count.Text = "0";
                nan_tafton_count.Text = "0";
                nan_mahali_count.Text = "0";
                nan_barbari_count.Focus();
                nan_barbari_count.SelectAll();
            }
            else if (success == 5)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("something");
            }
  }
  else MessageBox.Show("something");
```

@ Hans Passant, do that in in call stack i have these(its from first call of child form.), but i couldn't understand why form is closed, its all assembly references. can you understand why ?

```
        System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) + 0x6d bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x3f3 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessKeyPreview(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x43 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyPreview(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x16 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x1c bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x15 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x7dd bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x37 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x36 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x10 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x57 bytes 
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(int dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x24e bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x177 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) + 0x31 bytes  


    Nan_Behesht_winform.exe!Nan_Behesht_winform.call_order.call_order_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) Line 1308 C#
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnFormClosing(System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e) + 0x77 bytes
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckCloseDialog(bool closingOnly) + 0x8c bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FContinueMessageLoop(int reason, int pvLoopData, System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.MSG[] msgPeeked) + 0x160 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(int dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x1ae bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x177 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form form) + 0x33 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner) + 0x370 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() + 0x7 bytes 
Nan_Behesht_winform.exe!Nan_Behesht_winform.Main_Form.Main_Form_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e) Line 260 + 0xa bytes    C#
```

Comment: Override OnFormClosing in the dialog and set a breakpoint on it.  Look at the call stack when it hits to have a guess how the dialog got closed.

Comment: very well @Hans Passant, thanks for that, but i still confused, look at call stack see what you can find. thanks

Comment: Hard to imagine the first snippet is accurate, it immediately closes the dialog.  Looks to me the form object was used before and you didn't actually use *new call_order()*.  Explicitly set the form's DialogResult property to None before calling ShowDialog().

Comment: ok i did that by this code but same happened `call_order.DialogResult = DialogResult.None; 
                call_order.ShowDialog();` i add call stack from main form key press that show call_order form. give it a look ;)

Comment: i use `.show()` instead of `.ShowDialog()` and everything solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the DialogResult property on that button?

From [`Button.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) page on MSDN:

```
If the DialogResult for this property is set to anything other than None, and if
the parent form was displayed through the ShowDialog method, clicking the button
closes the parent form without your having to hook up any events.
```

Comment: no i didn't change `DialogResult` in child form `call_order`. i used `.show()` instead of `.ShowDialog()` child form doesn't close after button click. do you know why ?

Comment: To clarify, this property is found in the Properties pane of the form designer (or `Form1.designer.cs` if you prefer). Setting it via code does not automatically close the form.